# Javascript sort callback dosen't work for hash object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort the `hash object`, but it doesn't work.

It is so simple sample, and try snippet, but in vain.

Where am I wrong?

```js
function compareItem(a,b){
     console.log("a",a.class_id);
     console.log("b",b.class_id);
     console.log(a.class_id < b.class_id)　
     return a.class_id < b.class_id;
}
var arr = [{class_id:2},{class_id:1},{class_id:3}];
console.log(arr.sort(compareItem));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Compare function **MUST** return an integer, not boolean: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#parameters Change it to `return a.class_id - b.class_id` and see how it now works just fine.

Comment: ooooh That's right! it works well thank you very much.